# The changes made in excel in share point 2010 by one user is not visible to other user

Tags: document-library, excel

I am updating content of an excel sheet in a document library of SharePoint 2010, which is getting saved from my end but another user if he open, he is not able to see those changes made by me. Same is happening with me if he changes something.

I want to clarify the issue by an example.
Suppose there are 4 users A,B,C and D. What ever A is changing B is able to see and vice versa. But in the case of C and D whatever they are changing only those changes they can see (ex. if C is changing, only C can see it, none of A, B and D are able to see). Neither their changes are getting reflected to other nor other's changes getting reflected to them.
None of the person using any check in - check out. Even A and B are not using any check in and check out, still, their changes are getting reflected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If your library has enabled "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" then after making the changes in the file you have to **Check in & Publish** the document. Otherwise changes will only be visible to the person who made it.

Comment: I am site collection admin but still **Publish** button is disabled in my case.

Comment: Publish button will be enabled if you have selected "Create major and minor (draft) versions" in versioning setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behaviour on a document library that had a workflow applied. In the backend, click the little down-arrow on the document title and check for an option in the drop-down menu saying 'publish'.